# Merits of std::find

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, find, containers

Is there any advantage to using C++11's `std::find` over a container's `find` method?

- In the case of `std::vector` (which does not have a `find` method) does `std::find` use some smart algorithm or the naive way of simply iterating over every element?
- In the case of `std::map` it seems you need to pass along an `std::pair`, which is the `value_type` of an `std::map`. This does not seem very useful as usually you'd want to find for either a key or a mapped element.
- What about other containers like `std::list` or `std::set` or `std::unordered_set` ?

Comment: You can use `std::find_if` on `std::map` in order to compare only the key.  But it's better to use the `find` member function in this case, because of performance.  However, if for some reason you wanted to search the map by the value, you could use `find_if` in that case.

Comment: use the member function if it exists, and use `std::find` if it doesn't.

Comment: If you know your std::vector is actually sorted, there's always the option of using std::lower_bound() to do a binary search.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> In the case of std::vector (which does not have a find method) does std::find use some smart algorithm or the naive way of simply iterating over every element?

It cannot, because vectors are not sorted. There is no other way to find an element in an unsorted vector than a linear search with O(n) complexity.

On the other hand, sequence containers do not offer a `find()` member functions, so you could not possibly use that.

> In the case of std::map it seems you need to pass along an std::pair, which is the value_type of an std::map. This does not seem very useful as usually you'd want to find for either a key or a mapped element.

Indeed, here you should use the `find()` member function, which guarantees a better complexity (O(log N)).

In general, when a container exposes a member function with the same name as a generic algorithm, this is because the member function does the same thing, but offers a better complexity guarantee.

> What about other containers like std::list or std::set or std::unordered_set ?

Just like `std::vector`, `std::list` is not a sorted container - so the same conclusion applies.

For `std::set` and `std::unordered_set`, instead, you should use the `find()` member function, which guarantees a better complexity (O(log n) and average O(1), respectively).

Comment: So, what will be the find() operation complexity for string?

Comment: "Indeed, here you should use the find() member function" <- shouldn't `std::find` have a specialization which uses that method?