# What is the C++ equivalent of Python's "in" operator?

Tags: c++, arrays

What is the C++ way of checking if an element is contained in an array/list, similar to what the `in` operator does in Python?

```
if x in arr:
    print "found"
else
    print "not found"
```

How does the time complexity of the C++ equivalent compare to Python's `in` operator?

Comment: Maybe `find` can do what you need - see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find

Comment: @4386427 But you wouldn't want to use `std::find` on a map or set.

Comment: Or, if the container is sorted, [std::lower_bound](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) can be used. (or the member function if available eg. [std::map::lower_bound](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/lower_bound)).

Comment: So if you care about time complexity, unfortunately there is no syntactic equivalent that works well across all container types.

Comment: @juanchopanza - Since I'm not a Python man, I'm not sure what the equivalent type for `arr` would be in C++. If it's like a `map`, then there is a `find` public member function in `std::map`. Anyway, this was just a hint to OP that `find` could be something to look into. If I knew it was "the answer" I would have posted it as an answer but not knowing Python very well, I just left a comment.

Comment: `contains(container)` isn't that difficult to write: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/59997/contains-algorithm-for-stdvector

Comment: @EdgarRokyan What is the point of having [tag:C++11] and [tag:C++14] for this question?

Comment: @moooeeeep I've added them because a number of later answers are heavily based on features from C++11/14.

Comment: @EdgarRokyan That doesn't really matter. C++ is almost C++17, meaning it includes C++11 and C++14 features (except for things that have been "fixed" or deprecated.)

Comment: @juanchopanza so C++ is a general tag for C++11/14/17 now, and C++11/14 tags are used only for specific features of appropriate language versions, right?

Comment: @EdgarRokyan I think this applies: [Should I tag questions C++11 if they refer to the C++11 standard but not new features?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271812/1025391)

Comment: @moooeeeep yes, it exactly applies to the situation.

Comment: @EdgarRokyan C++ is current C++, C++11 could be used when one is restricted to a particular standard. Although if a standard is newly or abouyt to come out, it could make sense to tag answers with that particular standard too (e.g. c++17)

Comment: @juanchopanza I feel I did some bad edits a couple of times :)

Comment: The "in" operator feature is being implemented in https://github.com/ploncomi/python_like_cpp

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The time complexity of Python's `in` operator varies depending on the data structure it is actually called with. When you use it with a list, complexity is linear (as one would expect from an unsorted array without an index). When you use it to look up set membership or presence of a dictionary key complexity is constant on average (as one would expect from a hash table based implementation):

- https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

In C++ you can use `std::find` to determine whether or not an item is contained in a `std::vector`. Complexity is said to be linear (as one would expect from an unsorted array without an index). If you make sure the vector is sorted, you can also use `std::binary_search` to achieve the same in logarithmic time.

- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find
- [Check if element is in the list (contains)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24139428/1025391)
- [Check if element found in array c++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19215027/1025391)
- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/binary_search

The associative containers provided by the standard library (`std::set`, `std::unordered_set`, `std::map`, ...) provide the member functions `find()` and `count()` and `contains()` (C++20) for this. These will perform better than linear search, i.e., logarithmic or constant time depending on whether you have picked the ordered or the unordered alternative. Which one of these functions to prefer largely depends on what you want to achieve with that info afterwards, but also a bit on personal preference. (Lookup the documentation for details and examples.)

- [How to check that an element is in a std::set?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1701067/1025391)
- [How to check if std::map contains a key without doing insert?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3886593/1025391)
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_containers
- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container

If you want to, you can use some template magic to write a wrapper function that picks the correct method for the container at hand, e.g., as presented in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44634581/1025391).

Comment: _"The associative containers ... provide the `find()` method for this"_ - Does the `std::find` function have overloads that defer to these methods?

Comment: @Eric As the function takes Input-/Forward-Iterators, it seems to just forward-iterate the container.

Comment: (To actually answer the question:) There are no such overloads of `std::find`.

Comment: @Eric: Unfortunately, no. It's one of the reasons why the whole iterator-based interface of `<algorithm>` is, in hindsight, not a good idea, why ranges would be much better: with ranges you can specialize algorithms so that if the passed-in type has some properties/methods, you can defer to it.

Comment: @MatthieuM. The problem is not with the iterator-based interface; one can easily imagine a setup where `find` recognizes iterators from, say, an associative container, and the iterators contain (a pointer to) sufficient information to perform a binary search. The problem is that `find` is required to use `==`, which is not required to be consistent with any ordering the associative container might have (not even the default `<`).

Comment: @T.C.: I would imagine that should `find` delegate to the container/view being iterated, this requirement would change.

Answer (score 17):

You can approach this in two ways:

You can use [`std::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) from `<algorithm>`:

```
auto it = std::find(container.begin(), container.end(), value);
if (it != container.end())
    return it;
```

or you can iterate through every element in your containers with for ranged loops:

```
for(const auto& it : container)
{
    if(it == value)
        return it;
}
```

Comment: This wouldn't scale very well for sorted or unsorted sets or maps (O(N) vs. amortized O(log N) or O(1))

Comment: It's better to write for(const auto & it : container) to avoid unnessasary copy. Also the second approach, I think, should be on the fist place. Because it declares your intentions more clear

Comment: @AndreyNekrasov I edited the order. In some cases you might just want a copy of the value, but i agree, in most cases you would want a `const reference`.

Comment: Bad idea, for the reasons specified in my first comment.

Comment: @juanchopanza it's not exactly efficient in python either. (I believe it is O(n) on a list).  map::find is logarithmic in C++ (unless http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/find/ is wrong)

Comment: @Baldrickk: Does `std::find(map_iterator...)` forward to `std::map::find`, avoiding a linear search?

Comment: @Eric doesn't look like it, going by https://stackoverflow.com/a/17256035/2072269

Comment: @muru @Eric that's disappointing.  I don't have any problems with using `std::map::find()`, but it's not exactly promoting abstraction and reusability.  It makes you wonder why `std::find()` doesn't look to see if there is a member function `find()` and call that instead...

Comment: @Baldrickk hint: is it possible to [get back the original container from an iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11445040/2072269) (which is all that `std::find` sees)?

Comment: yeah, I get that. it's a shame that there isn't an overload that takes a container object, calls the object's `map()` if it exists and iterates over the entire container otherwise.but then you run into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14003627/stl-algorithms-why-no-additional-interface-for-containers-additional-to-iterat/14003766  I guess I have just been spoilt by Python recently. My C++ is getting rusty.

Comment: Eric : How can std::find() forward to map find? STL algorithms know _NOTHING_ about the containers they are operating on. They only know about iterator category types.

Comment: @Baldrickk Obviously it is O(N) in a list. But not in a set or dict. That is the whole point.

Comment: This is not a very good answer. In both snippets, what is the function we're returning from? What is the "else" case? That's even before you get into the question of using an O(N) search for those containers that have O(lg N) or O(1) searches available. -1.

Answer (score 14):

Python does different things for `in` depending on what kind of container it is. In C++, you'd want the same mechanism. Rule of thumb for the standard containers is that if they provide a `find()`, it's going to be a better algorithm than `std::find()` (e.g. `find()` for `std::unordered_map` is O(1), but `std::find()` is always O(N)).

So we can write something to do that check ourselves. The most concise would be to take advantage of C++17's `if constexpr` and use something like Yakk's [`can_apply`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29521342/2069064):

```
template <class C, class K>
using find_t = decltype(std::declval<C const&>().find(std::declval<K const&>()));

template <class Container, class Key>
bool in(Container const& c, Key const& key) {
    if constexpr (can_apply<find_t, Container, Key>{}) {
        // the specialized case
        return c.find(key) != c.end();
    } else {
        // the general case 
        using std::begin; using std::end;
        return std::find(begin(c), end(c), key) != end(c);
    }
}
```

In C++11, we can take advantage of expression SFINAE:

```
namespace details {
    // the specialized case
    template <class C, class K>
    auto in_impl(C const& c, K const& key, int )
            -> decltype(c.find(key), true) {
        return c.find(key) != c.end();
    }

    // the general case
    template <class C, class K>
    bool in_impl(C const& c, K const& key, ...) {
        using std::begin; using std::end;
        return std::find(begin(c), end(c), key) != end(c);
    }
}

template <class Container, class Key>
bool in(Container const& c, Key const& key) {
    return details::in_impl(c, key, 0);
}
```

Note that in both cases we have the `using std::begin; using std::end;` two-step in order to handle all the standard containers, raw arrays, and any use-provided/adapted containers.

Comment: `decltype(c.find(key) != c.end())` :)

Comment: @T.C. That's longer :-P

Comment: Not if you are in full-blown paranoia mode ;)

Answer (score 10):

This gives you an infix `*in*` operator:

```
namespace notstd {
  namespace ca_helper {
    template<template<class...>class, class, class...>
    struct can_apply:std::false_type{};
    template<class...>struct voider{using type=void;};
    template<class...Ts>using void_t=typename voider<Ts...>::type;

    template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts>
    struct can_apply<Z,void_t<Z<Ts...>>, Ts...>:std::true_type{};
  }
  template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts>
  using can_apply = ca_helper::can_apply<Z,void,Ts...>;

  namespace find_helper {
    template<class C, class T>
    using dot_find_r = decltype(std::declval<C>().find(std::declval<T>()));
    template<class C, class T>
    using can_dot_find = can_apply< dot_find_r, C, T >;
    template<class C, class T>
    constexpr std::enable_if_t<can_dot_find<C&, T>{},bool>
    find( C&& c, T&& t ) {
      using std::end;
      return c.find(std::forward<T>(t)) != end(c);
    }
    template<class C, class T>
    constexpr std::enable_if_t<!can_dot_find<C&, T>{},bool>
    find( C&& c, T&& t ) {
      using std::begin; using std::end;
      return std::find(begin(c), end(c), std::forward<T>(t)) != end(c);
    }
    template<class C, class T>
    constexpr bool finder( C&& c, T&& t ) {
      return find( std::forward<C>(c), std::forward<T>(t) );
    }
  }
  template<class C, class T>
  constexpr bool find( C&& c, T&& t ) {
    return find_helper::finder( std::forward<C>(c), std::forward<T>(t) );
  }
  struct finder_t {
    template<class C, class T>
    constexpr bool operator()(C&& c, T&& t)const {
      return find( std::forward<C>(c), std::forward<T>(t) );
    }
    constexpr finder_t() {}
  };
  constexpr finder_t finder{};
  namespace named_operator {
    template<class D>struct make_operator{make_operator(){}};

    template<class T, char, class O> struct half_apply { T&& lhs; };

    template<class Lhs, class Op>
    half_apply<Lhs, '*', Op> operator*( Lhs&& lhs, make_operator<Op> ) {
      return {std::forward<Lhs>(lhs)};
    }

    template<class Lhs, class Op, class Rhs>
    auto operator*( half_apply<Lhs, '*', Op>&& lhs, Rhs&& rhs )
    -> decltype( named_invoke( std::forward<Lhs>(lhs.lhs), Op{}, std::forward<Rhs>(rhs) ) )
    {
      return named_invoke( std::forward<Lhs>(lhs.lhs), Op{}, std::forward<Rhs>(rhs) );
    }
  }
  namespace in_helper {
    struct in_t:notstd::named_operator::make_operator<in_t> {};
    template<class T, class C>
    bool named_invoke( T&& t, in_t, C&& c ) {
      return ::notstd::find(std::forward<C>(c), std::forward<T>(t));
    }
  }
  in_helper::in_t in;
}
```

On a flat container, like a vector array or string, it is O(n).

On an associative sorted container, like a `std::map`, `std::set`, it is O(lg(n)).

On an unordered associated container, like `std::unordered_set`, it is O(1).

Test code:

```
std::vector<int> v{1,2,3};
if (1 *in* v)
    std::cout << "yes\n";
if (7 *in* v)
    std::cout << "no\n";
std::map<std::string, std::string, std::less<>> m{
    {"hello", "world"}
};
    
if ("hello" *in* m)
    std::cout << "hello world\n";
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/efd7ec973db5e11e).

C++14, but mainly for `enable_if_t`.

So what is going on here?

Well, `can_apply` is a bit of code that lets me write `can_dot_find`, which detects (at compile time) if `container.find(x)` is a valid expression.

This lets me dispatch the searching code to use member-find if it exists.  If it doesn't exist, a linear search using `std::find` is used instead.

Which is a bit of a lie.  If you define a free function `find(c, t)` in the namespace of your container, it will use that rather than either of the above.  But that is me being fancy (and it lets you extend 3rd party containers with `*in*` support).

That ADL (argument dependent lookup) extensibity (the 3rd party extension ability) is why we have three different functions named `find`, two in a helper namespace and one in `notstd`.  You are intended to call `notstd::find`.

Next, we want a python-like `in`, and what is more python like than an infix operator?  To do this in C++ you need to wrap your operator name in other operators.  I chose `*`, so we get an infix `*in*` named operator.

---

## TL;DR

You do `using notstd::in;` to import the named operator `in`.

After that, `t *in* c` first checks if `find(t,c)` is valid.  If not, it checks if `c.find(t)` is valid.  If that fails, it does a linear search of `c` using `std::begin` `std::end` and `std::find`.

This gives you very good performance on a wide variety of `std` containers.

The only thing it doesn't support is

```
if (7 *in* {1,2,3})
```

as operators (other than `=`) cannot deduce initializer lists I believe.  You could get

```
if (7 *in* il(1,2,3))
```

to work.

Comment: Wow, this form of sorcery is what makes C++ fun

Answer (score 9):

I guess one might make use of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21660325/disambiguate-template-specialization-between-map-like-and-vector-like-containers) thread and create a custom version of `in` function.

The main idea is to use [SFINAE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error) (Substitution Failure Is Not An Error) to differentiate associative containers (which have *key_type* member) from sequence containers (which have no *key_type* member).

Here is a possible implementation:

```
namespace detail
{
    template<typename, typename = void>
    struct is_associative : std::false_type {};

    template<typename T>
    struct is_associative<T,
        std::enable_if_t<sizeof(typename T::key_type) != 0>> : std::true_type {};

    template<typename C, typename T>
    auto in(const C& container, const T& value) ->
        std::enable_if_t<is_associative<C>::value, bool>
    {
        using std::cend;

        return container.find(value) != cend(container);
    }

    template<typename C, typename T>
    auto in(const C& container, const T& value) ->
        std::enable_if_t<!is_associative<C>::value, bool>
    {
        using std::cbegin;
        using std::cend;

        return std::find(cbegin(container), cend(container), value) != cend(container);
    }

}

template<typename C, typename T>
auto in(const C& container, const T& value)
{
    return detail::in(container, value);
}
```

Small usage example on [**WANDBOX**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/7lYmg5lvrE0kBJsF).

Comment: In order to enable SFINAE for this case, you have to add on top of your code `/* deliberately killing KISS */`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `std::find` from `<algorithm>`, but this works only for datatypes like: `std::map` and `std::vector` (etc).

Also note that this will return, iterator to the first element that is found equal to the value you pass, unlike the `in` operator in Python that returns a bool.

Answer (score 0):

I think one of the nice features of the "in" operator in python is that it can be used with different data types (strings v/s strings, numbers v/s lists, etc).

I am developing a library for using python constructions in C++. It includes "in" and "not_in" operators.

It is based on the same technique used to implement the *in* operator posted in a previous answer, in which make_operator<in_t> is implemented. However, it is extended for handling more cases:

- Searching a string inside a string
- Searching an element inside vector and maps

It works by defining several overloads for a function: `bool in__(T1 &v1, T2 &v2)`, in which T1 and T2 consider different possible types of objects. Also, overloads for a function: `bool not_in__(T1 &v1, T2 &v2)` are defined. Then, the operators "in" and "not_in" call those functions for working.

The implementation is in this repository:

https://github.com/ploncomi/python_like_cpp

Comment: We generally prefer an answer within the answer, rather than a link to an answer somewhere else. Could you provide an explanation instead?

Comment: Sorry, but it was not the link to an answer, it is a link to a repository which implements the requested feature (I am working on it). I will modify my answer for being more explicative.